# How to plot data averaged by month and day?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I would like to reproduce that plot:

[image: link]

from [link](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/kaggle-competition.pdf)

I'm almost able to do that but I miss something:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
# get the data
dates <- seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-30"), by = 1)
series <- seq(from = 1, to = 1095, by = 1)
df<-data.frame(dates,series)

# for aggregation
df$month<-as.numeric(format(df$date, "%m"))
df$week<-week(as.POSIXct(df$date))
df$weekday<-weekdays(as.POSIXct(df$date))
df$days<-as.numeric(format(df$date, "%d"))
df$week_days<-as.numeric(format(df$date, "%w"))

# for plotting
for_plot=aggregate(series ~ + weekday+ month, data =df, FUN=mean)


ggplot(for_plot, aes(x=weekday, y=series)) + geom_line(aes(group=month, color=month),size=2,alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: The plot from the paper was created using Base R.  If you want to duplicate it exactly, you should start with the `plot()` function and maybe use a combination of `lines()` and `points()`.  Otherwise, what aspects of the plot from the paper are you trying to duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close!
Just two little changes to the `class` of the **for_plot** columns:

Change *month* to factor to get one color per month

```
for_plot$month = as.factor(for_plot$month)
```

As *weekday* is a `character` ggplot by default tries to sort it as characters. To prevent this turn *weekday* in a `factor` and specify the levels.

```
for_plot$weekday = factor(for_plot$weekday, 
        levels = c("Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))
```

As you run R with a german locale you have do do it in German, so `levels=c("Montag",...,"Sonntag")`

To get the dots on the line just add `geom_point` as follows:

```
ggplot(for_plot, aes(weekday, series, group=month, col=month)) + 
   geom_line() +
   geom_point()
```

This gives you

[image]

Comment: Hope not bother you too much, but is there I way, a shortcut, to produce the same plot just for 2013 rather then for the complete period? Thank you!

Comment: You can do `df_2013  <- df[year(df$dates)==2013]` and then aggregate `df_2013`